# SQL Primary Key Increment

Tags: sql, firebird

How can I have a primary key that auto increments?
for example: when I insert something at the field name, the field id should be assign a value that is +1 that the last one.

```
id, name
 1, test1
 2, test2
```

so I insert the name something like testX and the id should be auto assigned as 3

how can i do that?

Comment: Use a server side generator?

Comment: Why did you tag this Q `[delphi]`? It's clearly IB/Firebird question.

Comment: @FreeConsulting well, the next question would be Delphi-related, he would ask which libraries support INSERT-RETURNING or other legacy ways of fetching auto-generated id back into the app :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to answer of ain, you can use [generator](https://firebirdsql.org/manual/generatorguide.html) like :

***Create a generator :***

```
CREATE GENERATOR <name>;
SET GENERATOR <name> TO <value>;
```

***Getting the current value of generator:***

```
SELECT GEN_ID( <GeneratorName>, 0 ) FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

***Generating the next value***

```
 SELECT GEN_ID( <GeneratorName>, 1 ) FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

***Using generator in trigger***

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger <trigger_name>_bi for <table_name>
active before insert position 0
as
begin
  if (new.id is null) then
    new.id = gen_id(my_generator,1);
end
```

**If you want numeration without holes you have to be very careful.**

Generators/Sequences are  non-transactional.
Once you get a value if your operation fails, you will have a hole.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Firebird 3 then you can use the [identity column](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity) feature:

```
create table T (
  id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
  ...
);
```

If you're using some older version of Firebird, then using an sequence with trigger can be used to achieve the autoincrement:

```
create table T (
  id integer primary key,
  ...
);

CREATE SEQUENCE t_seq;

create trigger t_gen_id
  active before insert
  on T
as
begin
  if(new.id is null)then new.id = next value for t_seq;
end;
```

Since Firebird 2 the [returning clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-insert.html#langrefupd25-insert-returning) is supported which is very handy to get the id value generated on the server side.